# CGAL 2D Delaunay Triangulation: How to get all the edges

Tags: triangulation, cgal, delaunay

How to get/iterate over all the edges in the 2D delaunay graph in CGAL (C++)?

For example, in MATLAB this is just edges(dt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to use members functions 
All_edges_iterator all_edges_begin()
All_edges_iterator all_edges_end()
to get the iterator range over edges.

It is documented on the Triangulation_2 page [here](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/beta/doc_html/cgal_manual/Triangulation_2_ref/Class_Triangulation_2.html#Function_All_edges_iterator_all_edges_begin69_const;)

Note that you will get edges incident to the infinite vertex together with finite edges.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to CGAL. How to extract finite edges only?

Comment: finite_edges_begin(), finite_edges_end() returning objects of type Finite_edges_iterator